# ComboBox DataBinding interface

Tags: c#, combobox, interface

I´m creating a main solution that is supposed to have lots of plugins for reading data an transferring this to the main solution. 
Therefore I created an interface and a MainApp holding some Settings:

```
public interface IPlugin{
  string pluginName();
  uint uniqueID();
}

public class Setting{
  string settingName{get;set;}
  IPlugin plugin{get;set;}
}
```

In the end of the day my main application has:

```
public class mainApp{
  list <Setting> SettingList;
  comboBox SettingComboBox;
  comboBox PluginComboBox;
}
```

I want to add a DataBinding to change PluginComboBox according to it´s stored value (which is loaded by Deserialisation).

I tried

```
pluginComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", settingBindingSource, "plugin", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

But the ComboBox does not change accordingly.

Comment: Maybe a secondary task:
The _PluginComboBox_ shows the `ToString` Override of `IPlugin`. Is there any way to bind `DisplayMember`and/or `ValueMember` to an interfaces methods?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, one should sleep prior posting.

Above code is working as expected.
The problem was that `setting.plugin` was `null` on instantiating the binding and filled afterwards.

Solution -> fill the bound object prior creating the binding.